# why should we avoid installing Node.js with apt-get on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, curl, npm

why should we avoid installing Node.js with apt-get on Ubuntu? And, how does using curl and the nodejs PPA solve the problem? (**Hint:** It has got to do with being able to install npm modules globally. But, if so, why should we install npm modules globally?)

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash`
`sudo apt install nodejs`
`npm -v`

(Also, I want to run React with npm here)

Comment: where did you hear/read this?

Comment: @bolov go to "on linux" part - https://yoember.com/nodejs/the-best-way-to-install-node-js/

Comment: probably to have control over the version that you want to install ? e.g. `apt install nodejs` will install latest stable version, while `https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_Y.x` will install latest stable version of Y.

Comment: @SmritiMittal you should [edit] your question to include the source of this advice (link and quotes). Not familiar in this area, but it looks like a random site. It's a difference between say an official documentation and a random tutorial site on the web.  So the source of the advice is important

Comment: This has nothing to do with installing npm modules globally.

Comment: Also sounds like a homework question.

Comment: @James Hibbard No, it's not. I came up with it while reading through this - https://yoember.com/nodejs/the-best-way-to-install-node-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, the answer to **"Which is the best way to install node?"** is actually **"it depends"**, at least, in my opinion.

> Why it depends? Well, quite easy, I see at least 2 cases why it could be so, clearly, there will be more, meaning, there is no "best way to install nodejs" which will make installing it via apt-get sometimes useful.

**Case 1:**

If you are running in a development environment, probably the case is that this is not the only place in which you are going to have a node app. Probably, you are going to be having different node applications, and at some point you will probably have some apps that won't work unless they are in a specific version, being `4.X.X` or `8.9.X` or others.

This means that you will need different kind of versions in the same machine and you will need to be able to change them on the fly (or at least easily right?). For this is for what `nvm` was created. To manage several versions in the same machine, and just typing `nvm use 8.9.13` would make ur system use that version in that specific time, which is super useful. Because of this case this is the recommended method, but that doesn't mean it's the best.

**Case 2:**

If you are running on production, the situation changes. You want to have in the machine as little as possible, and as many as possible trusted sources as there could possibly be. This means that either you could use the `apt-get install` command or you could even go with something more fancy/heavy but trustable like a `docker container` a `Vagrant machine` or other "virtualization/provisioning" software that would enable you to know ***exacly*** what you are running inside.

The setup in this case pretty much depends of the requirements of the app. But most likely (I am like 98% confident about this) **you shouldn't be using `nvm` in your production machine(s)**. But I won't say now here why, as it would make the answer way too long. This is a question for another time.